# Append to data file to file using python

Tags: python, file, append

I need help taking data from file a to file b and appending to both sides of it.  so file a has a list of numbers and I want to put it on a new file but appending `"<jno> 1st piece of data from file a <\jno>\n"`

Here is my code as of now....

```python
def code(filename):

    file=open(filename)

    FinishFile=open("JimmenyCricketsXML.txt","w")

    FinishFile.write('<team>\n')
    FinishFile.write('<crickets>\n')


    for element in file:
        FinishFile.write('<jno>'+ str(element) + '<\jno>\n')
```

my results are:

```
<jno>element

<\jno>
```

why does it skip to the next line?

Comment: So, are you getting an error message, or what?

Comment: yeah it splits it line 1 saying '<jno>element, line 2 <\jno>

Comment: Does your element string contain new lines?

Comment: Does writing `\j` actually output "\j", is that guaranteed?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
   FinishFile.write('<jno>'+ str(element) + '<\jno>\n')
```

with:

```
   FinishFile.write('<jno>'+ str(element).strip() + '<\jno>\n')
```

To remove leading and trailing whitespace characters (including linebreaks).

If you only want to remove linebreaks and no other spaces etc., use this line instead:

```
   FinishFile.write('<jno>'+ str(element).strip('\n') + '<\jno>\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use:

```
FinishFile.write('<jno>'+ str(element).strip('\n') + '</jno>\n')
```

Or

```
FinishFile.write('<jno>'+ str(element).strip('\n') + '<\\jno>\n')
```